# gdb tui, dl-debug.c:74 no such file or directory

Tags: gdb, tui

If I start `gdb -tui` or `gdbtui` with an `-g` flag compiled file, then set `b main` and press `r` I get the hint `dl-debug.c:74 no such file or directory` and the output while stepping through the source window will be written to the source window at the bottom, which also messes up this window so that is not really readable. I've already looked at [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/) and [Sourceware Bugzilla – Bug List](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&component=tui&product=gdb) and at this site but found no solution.

I also tried out `sudo apt-get install ddd` on another machine to go to the trouble out of the way, but then I only get authentication failure, which I also [already asked without response on ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806731/authentication-fails-while-installing-ddd).

Any help or hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `dl-debug.c:74 no such file or directory`

This message means that you've tried to step into GLIBC (more precisely the dynamic loader) source, which you didn't install.

Solution: don't try to step into it, or install GLIBC source and make GDB find it (`help directory`).

Comment: `ldd --version` displays that I have `EGLIBC 2.19` does this matters?

Comment: @JohnGoofy No, it doesn't.

Comment: Okay, I will try it out tomorrow. Recently I updated GDB from 7.7 to 7.11.1 and got rid of the message `dl-debug.c:74 no such file or directory` but got a new one: `Python Exception <type 'exceptions.NameError'> Installation error: gdb.execute_unwinders function is missing;`. It occurs exactly like the error before, after typing `b main` and `r` in `gdb -tui`.

Comment: @JohnGoofy The "installation error" means just that: you didn't install GDB correctly (parts of it are missing). That error will persist until you do correct and *complete* installation.

Comment: I followed the instrutctions from [link]http://askubuntu.com/questions/529781/upgrade-from-gdb-7-7-to-7-8/529795#529795. I don't know what's went wrong.

Comment: @JohnGoofy The instructions you followed are simply *wrong*. Instead of `make; sudo cp ...`, you need to `make; sudo make install`. It used to be that GDB was a single `gdb` binary. This is no longer the case: you now need Python support files as well.

Comment: Yes! This works! Thank you very much! The soulution have been changing `make; sudo cp ...` to `make; sudo make install`. Well done!